# Symfony - can't delete record

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am testing delete action in Postman. I created a delete action and it keeps returning 'success' and when I refresh the database my row with forwarded parameter(of id = 1) is still there.

My Service.

```
    /**
 * Delete user
 * @param $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function deleteUser($id)
{
    $query = $this->getUserRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('du')
        ->delete('ProjectBundle:User','du')
        ->where('du.id = :id')
        ->setParameter("id", $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();

    return $query;

}
```

Controller.

```
/**
 * @Route("/users/delete/{id}", name="user_delete")
 * @param $id
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
 * @throws \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException
 */
public function getUserDeleteAction($id)
{
    $this->get('user')->deleteUser($id);

    return $this->success();
}
```

I think this is the right way and don't know where the problem could be.

Comment: I don't know what succes() does but it does not seem to be related in any way to deleteUser().

Comment: Can you see your query in profiler > doctrine?

Comment: Um, do you have softdelete?

Comment: Yes, I can. And I think I don't have softdelete?

Answer (score 2):

You must use the `->remove()` method, like this:

```
#controller
public function getUserDeleteAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($id);
    $em->remove($user);

    return $this->success();
}
```

Info [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#removing-entities).

Comment: It comes as an error.. "EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, NULL given.
"

Comment: That most likely means there is no user with the id contained in $id

Comment: @FilipStojanovic yep, TobiasXy is right, you have to have some users in your mysql table, managed by Doctrine